# How to build g++ 4.5.2 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

My gcc compiler is a bit outdated - gcc 4.3, so I want to build a new gcc from source since I ran apt-get update, but there were no pre-built version available yet.
Has anyone experienced this process before?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: consider asking in http://askubuntu.com ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install new version of GMP, MPFR, MPC from sources:

```
curl -O http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-5.0.1.tar.gz
tar zxf gmp-5.0.1.tar.gz
cd gmp-5.0.1/
./configure --prefix=/usr
sudo make install
cd ..

curl -O http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr-3.0.0.tar.gz
tar zxf mpfr-3.0.0.tar.gz
cd mpfr-3.0.0/
./configure --prefix=/usr
sudo make install
cd ..

curl -O http://www.multiprecision.org/mpc/download/mpc-0.8.2.tar.gz
tar zxf mpc-0.8.2.tar.gz 
cd mpc-0.8.2/
./configure --prefix=/usr
sudo make install
```

Comment: It is usually a better idea to install these through packages:

sudo apt-get build-dep gcc-4.5

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to download the source packages.  You can get the from http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

Next you're going to want to install the package `build-essentials` from apt.  Use the following command:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Next you're going to want to extract the source package to its own directory:

```
mkdir -p ~/compiling/gcc
cd !$
tar -zxvf ~/path/to/downloaded/gcc-4.5.2.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.5.2
```

Then you're going to want to compile it, usually the process is as follows:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

However, if you omit the last part you can still run the program by calling it directly, while keeping your currently installed version of gcc for normal use.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps from GNU website and got gcc installed perfectly:
http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html

Basically, you will need to install

- gmp-5.0.1
- mpc-0.8.2
- mpfr-3.0.0

and other libraries mentioned can be found under Synaptic Package Manager.

That's all